# Getting NullPointerException with autowired Component

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is the class I am trying to autowire:

```
package com.myproject.propdrone.lib;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;
import org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MapperOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class MongoDriver {
    private final Morphia morphia;
    private final Datastore datastore;

    MongoDriver() {
        morphia = new Morphia();
        datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "propdrone");
        MapperOptions options = morphia.getMapper().getOptions();
        options.setStoreEmpties(true);
        options.setStoreNulls(true);
        morphia.mapPackage("com.myproject.propdrone.models");
        datastore.ensureIndexes();
    }

    Datastore getDatastore() {
        return datastore;
    }
}
```

Here is the class where I am autowiring it:

```
package com.myproject.propdrone.lib;
//other imports here
@Component
public class BuildingDataDAO {
    @Autowired
    private MongoDriver mongoDriver;
    private Datastore datastore;
    private List<BuildingData> allBuildingData;

    public BuildingDataDAO() {
        datastore = mongoDriver.getDatastore(); // THIS FAILS
        allBuildingData = getAllBuildingData();
    }
    // other class definitions
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` thrown for the mongoDriver variable.

The main application class sits in the package `com.myproject` and it is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` so it should automatically scan those components. But I don't understand why it is failing.

**EDIT:**
I have modified BuildingDataDTO to use a @PostConstruct but I am still facing the issue:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void initDatastore() {
        datastore = mongoDriver.getDatastore();
    }
```

In a different class I am instantiating BuildingDataDTO normally as:

```
private final BuildingDataDAO buildingDataDAO = new BuildingDataDAO();
```

and when a method is called on *buildingDataDAO* which uses datastore, I get a *NullPointerException*.

Comment: You need to remove the `private` access specifier whenever you use `@Autowired`annotation.

Comment: I made the mongoDriver variable in BuildingDataDTO public but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't see the constructor inside `BuildingDataDAO`. You should remove the constructor and initialize the remaining attributes while declaring them or create beans for each of those attributes and initialize them with `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: How do you expect Spring to inject a dependency into an object that is still being constructed? You are trying to access the field in the constructor, however the field is getting injected **after** the object has been constructed. Either use constructor injection instead of field injection of use an `@PostConstruct` annotated method to do the initialization.

Comment: @M.Deinum Done that. Still failing. I have edited the question.

Comment: You are now creating an ew instance yourself... Spring will only inject instances it knows about.

Answer (score 0):

two issues:
1. disable SpringBoot's autoconfiguration example:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class,   MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class TestMorphiaApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TestMorphiaApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

2. the following works with your example

   @Component
   public class BuildingDataDAO {
       @Autowired
       private MongoDriver mongoDriver;
       private Datastore datastore;

   ```
   public BuildingDataDAO() {
   }

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
     datastore = mongoDriver.getDatastore();
   }
   ```

   }